# Replace dot in datafusion wrangler not working

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I need to remove dots from a number in Google DataFusion. For this I'm using the Wrangler transformation, but I'm having troubles with one file, because if I replace the dots, the whole cells gets empty.
If I replace any other character, it works.
What can be the trouble?

Thanks!

Original Value:
[image]
After replacing dots (.) :
[image]

Same cell/row but replacing spaces and number 1
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find and replace function of the wrangler is similar with "sed" wherein it applies [regular expressions](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html).

> Period (.) matches any character except a newline character.

Here is the original data:
[image]

I tried this on my own project and here is the result when using the un-escaped period:

[image]

[image]

You need to escape the period symbol (.) so it will treat it as a regular period. Here is the result when escaping period:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the period(.) was removed before "jpg".

Comment: That worked. I thinkg that the dot should be automatically scaped from the interface... it's a bit confusing considering that there no advice related to that!